# Decrypt TLS from an IDS

Tags: tls, ids, wireshark

So I am trying to figure out what the packet payload is off of a possible TLS HeartBleed alert from my IDS. I have read that Wireshark is able to do it with some certain keys, but isn't that in real time (ish). Would I be able to put that capture into wireshark if I can use the certificate from my server?

I believe it would be the .cer one right?

Comment: If you have the entire TLS session (handshake and all for both sides) and the private key, you should be able to decrypt captures.

Comment: Well from what I can see... I have the packet payload. So I do not think I have the entire session. What kind of file is the private key?

Comment: Depends on how it was generated.  .key, .p12.  You need the entire session in order to decrypt packets.

Comment: Oh, so that would be the key for my ssl? okay, I have that then. How would I know what the handshake looks like (still doubting I have it in my IDS)

Comment: You shouldn't need to decrypt at all. Heartbeat is not encrypted and its different record *type* (24, 0x18) is distinguishable from any encrypted-data (or handshake) record. (You *can* decrypt only IF: you have initial full handshake and server privatekey AND session used plain-RSA key-exchange, which up-to-date servers and clients both should discourage; OR you have initial handshake even abbreviated and your endpoint logged the session master or premaster secret, which a secure endpoint never should.)

Comment: Alrighty, makes more sense. Thank you for the insight, as well as @raz

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not need to decrypt the Packet since it most likely contains no useful information. If you look into the Packet with Wireshark you should see that the Type of (atleast one) TLS-Record in the Packet is 0x18 (Heartbeat Protocol). The (decrypted) Heartbeat Message contains two TLS-Fields: HeartbeatLength and HeartbeatPayload. If your IDS was able to decrypt the Record, it probably saw that the HeartbeatLength in the Record was greater than the number of HeartbeatPayload Bytes. If the Server too which this Packet was sent is vulnerable to Heartbleed, this packet would have triggered the famous Heartbleed vulnerability. On the other Hand, if your IDS cannot decrypt Records, it probably just didn't like Heartbeat Messages in general.